# jQuery/Wordpress - How to integrate jCarousel to the NivoSlider Thumbs?

Tags: jquery, wordpress, image-gallery

The base plugin I'm using is Nextgen Gallery. Then comes the Nextgen jSlider that adds nivo slider capabilities to the plugin. Only problem is that I need the thumbs to be inside a jCarousel. I've managed to modify the slider jquery script to put the images in an ul and to initialize the jcarousel.

**Here's the code I put in the `<head>`:**

```
<script src="/wp-content/themes/twentyten/jquery.jcarousel.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script> 
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/wp-content/themes/twentyten/skin.css" type="text/css" media="all" /> 
<script type="text/javascript"> 

jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    jQuery('#navCarousel').jcarousel();
});

</script>
```

**Here's the html code that is generated by the thumbnails nivo jquery script**

```
<div class="nivo-controlNav" style="visibility: visible; ">
  <ul id="navCarousel" class="jcarousel-skin-tango">
    <li><a class="nivo-control" rel="0"><img src="/test/thumbs/thumbs_5.jpg" alt=""></a></li>
    <li><a class="nivo-control" rel="1"><img src="/test/thumbs/thumbs_1.jpg" alt=""></a></li>
    <li><a class="nivo-control" rel="2"><img src="/test/thumbs/thumbs_2.jpg" alt=""></a></li>
    <li><a class="nivo-control" rel="3"><img src="/test/thumbs/thumbs_3.jpg" alt=""></a></li>
    <li><a class="nivo-control active" rel="4"><img src="/test/thumbs/thumbs_4.jpg" alt=""></a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

It **kinda works**  when I save the page in my browser and open the local file again (the jquery is inactive though). Here's what it looks like when I do that: [link](http://img708.imageshack.us/img708/6928/offlinet.jpg)

**I'd appreciate any kind of input. Thanks.**

If not, do you know of any other plugin that can do the ***[same thing](http://themeforest.s3.amazonaws.com/86_jquery/screenshots/1.jpg)***?

All the best,
Cris

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try anyone among these:

http://www.dynamicwp.net/articles-and-tutorials/20-beautiful-wordpress-slideshow-plugins/

Awesome plugins specially for wordpress themes.

Comment: Excellent. Looks like I have over there all I need. Thanks!